# Null values in where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, null

First I'd like to say that I understand that you cannot compare `null` in a where clause without using `is null` or is `not null`. My problem is that with the query below, the where clause doesn't always return null. It only returns null when there are no records in the select statement within the parenthesis.

I'm looking for a way to handle nulls returned from the select statement in the where clause. This query should return a list of Routes that are not listed in a table. This will be utilized so that users can only see what is not in the table yet.

Could I potentially use an `if` select returns null then select all?

```
declare @CollectionDate datetime = '11/25/2014'
declare @Inspector int = 12

SELECT RouteID,CONVERT(nvarchar(10), RouteID) + ' - ' + AbbreviatedRoute AS [RouteName] 
FROM MasterTable.TrapTruckRoutes 
where routeID <>

(

select a.routeID 
from Trapping.RainDetail a 
join trapping.Rain b 
on a.RainID = b.RainID 
where b.CollectionDate = @collectionDate 
and b.InspectorID = @inspector

)

ORDER BY RouteID
```

Comment: Love the down vote with no comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like a LEFT JOIN, which will select all records from the left table and join it with records in the right table where there is a match. No match will have null values.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT X.RouteID,CONVERT(nvarchar(10), X.RouteID) + ' - ' + AbbreviatedRoute AS [RouteName] 
FROM MasterTable.TrapTruckRoutes AS X LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT A.routeID 
    FROM Trapping.RainDetail A 
    JOIN trapping.Rain B 
    ON A.RainID = B.RainID 
    WHERE B.CollectionDate = @collectionDate 
                AND B.InspectorID = @inspector
) AS Y
ON X.routeID = Y.routeID
WHERE Y.routeID IS NULL
ORDER BY X.RouteID
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT RouteID,
       CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), RouteID) + ' - '
       + AbbreviatedRoute AS [RouteName]
FROM   MasterTable.TrapTruckRoutes b
WHERE  routeID = (SELECT CASE
                           WHEN a.routeID IS NULL THEN b.routeID
                           ELSE a.routeID
                         END
                  FROM   Trapping.RainDetail a
                         JOIN trapping.Rain b
                           ON a.RainID = b.RainID
                  WHERE  b.CollectionDate = @collectionDate
                         AND b.InspectorID = @inspector)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
DECLARE @CollectionDate DATETIME = '20141125';
DECLARE @Inspector INT = 12;

SELECT  RouteID,
        RouteName = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), RouteID) + ' - ' + AbbreviatedRoute 
FROM    MasterTable.TrapTruckRoutes AS ttr
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    Trapping.RainDetail AS rd
                    INNER JOIN trapping.Rain AS r
                        ON r.RainID = rd.RainID
            WHERE   r.CollectionDate = @CollectionDate
            AND     r.InspectorID = @Inspector
            AND     rd.RouteID = ttr.RouteID
        );
```

It handles `NULL` properly (which `NOT IN` won't), and won't cause an error if your subquery returns more than one row (using `<>` will cause an error), and is able to use an anti-semi join resulting in [better performance](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/) than using `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL`.

I've made a few changes to your code too, most of which are straight out of [Aaron Bertrand's "Bad Habits to Kick" series](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-revival/)

- [Using more meaningful table aliases rather than `(a, b, c etc)`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)
- [Terminate statements with Semi-Colons](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons)
- [Use `AS` for table aliases](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases)
- [Use the culture invariant `DATETIME` format `yyyyMMdd`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Some of these are a little subjective, but I think each article makes a pretty compelling case for each change.